# Excel-VBA: Add Folder-Explorer to Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, frame

I want to embed an explorer-window into my excel worksheet, to display some folder contents that are related to my workbook.

I use the following code, which works quiet well:

```
Sub AddOleBrowser()
    Dim OleBrowser As OleObject
    Dim Browser As Object

    Set OleBrowser = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Shell.Explorer.1", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False)
    Set Browser = OleBrowser.Object
    Browser.Navigate "X:\" 'Actually some network-path related to my workbook-path

    OleBrowser.Activate
End Sub
```

My problem is, that the OleBrowser keeps getting replaced by a low-res image, displaying the contents of the folder instead, whenever I click somewhere into my worksheet. When I double-click it, it returns to the normal browser view until it loses focus again. I want to add multiple browser windows to my worksheet, so they all should stay "activated".

I also tried to add a frame instead, which then holds a browserobject:

```
Sub AddOleFrameWithBrowser()
    Dim OleFrame As OleObject
    Dim CtrlBrowser As Control
    Dim Browser As Object
    Set OleFrame = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add("Forms.Frame.1", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False)
    Set CtrlBrowser = OleFrame.Object.Controls.Add("Shell.Explorer.2", "Browser") 'Frame1 is an MSForms.Frame-object that I placed there before.

    CtrlBrowser.Left = 0
    CtrlBrowser.Top = 0
    CtrlBrowser.Width = OleFrame.InsideWidth
    CtrlBrowser.Height = OleFrame.InsideHeight

    Set Browser = CtrlBrowser.Object
    Browser.Navigate "X:\" 'Actually some network-path related to my workbook-path

    OleFrame.Activate
End Sub
```

The second option works somewhat OK but when I switch to another worksheet and return, my frame is empty and I can't get a valid reference to my "Browser" control.

```
Sub CheckFrame()
    '
    Dim CheckBrowser As Object
    Set CheckBrowser = ActiveSheet.OleObjects(1).Object.Controls("Browser").Object
    Stop
    'CheckBrowser now actually contains the correct WebBrowser-object,
    'but when I run this sub (after I return to my Worksheet
    'with the Frame-OleObject) all it's properties either
    'contain falsified data or may not be accessed by the debugger...
    'Everything is fine, when I run this sub right after
    'my AddOleFrameWithBrowser()-Sub.
    ActiveSheet.OleObjects(1).Activate '<- Does not help
End Sub
```

Additionally whenever I try to do something with the folder-items inside my embedded explorer, it displays some security warning because the path is not on my local machine. This warning does not appear when I add the Shell.Explorer-OleObject directly with AddOleBrowser().

Could someone please give me some advice?

Comment: Re the security warning, have you tried adding the folder to your trusted locations?

Comment: No I didn't. But that would work for me only anyway... It's a document that is used by many of my colleagues so they would get the warning message all the time.